# A basic question about the convergence a sequence of measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ be probability  space i.e. $\mu(X)=1$. If $\{g_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of measurable functions such that $\Sigma_n \int g_n^2 d\mu <\infty$ then $g_n \to 0$ $\mu$-almost everywhere.

---

Attempt: Suppose $g_n\nrightarrow 0$ $\mu$-almost everwhere. Then $\mu(A)>0$ where $A:=\{x\in X: \lim g_n(x)\neq 0\}$. Since $A\subseteq B$ (*here I use the fact that* $\lim g_n^2=\lim g_n\lim g_n $), we have $\mu(B)>0$ where $B:=\{x\in X: \lim g_n^2(x)> 0 \}$. So $0<\int_B\lim g_n^2 d\mu=lim\int_B g_n^2d\mu$ by the monotone convergence theorem. So $\Sigma_n\int_Bg_n^2d\mu=\infty$, contradiction.

Can anyone check my attempt? And I am not sure the convergence in the question whether it is convergence in measure or not. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain how you argue that $\lim \int_B g_n^2 d\mu \neq 0$?

Comment: I've changed my attempt.

Comment: @Ergin MCT does not work for any sequence of measurable functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternate approach would be to consider
$$
a_n := \int g_n^2 \, \mathrm{d} \mu
$$
then we have that
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n <\infty
$$
thus we must have $a_n \to 0$. Then by non-negativity of the integrand we get that $g_n^2 \to 0$ and so $g_n \to 0$.

---

As for your attempt you seem to assume $g_n$ still converges to *something*, but I don't think this can be assumed.

As for whether this is asking about convergence in measure or not I do not think so,  generally [convergence $\mu$ almost everywhere](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlmostEverywhereConvergence.html) means a function converges pointwise almost everywhere (so except on a set of measure zero).

Comment: @John assume $g_n \not\to 0$ then there is some subsequence such that $\lvert g_n(x) \rvert > \epsilon$ for every $x \in E$ for some $E$ with $\mu(E) > 0$ and for some $\epsilon > 0$. Continue without relabling the subsequence then $g_n^2 > \epsilon^2$ on $E$ and so $\int g_n^2 \ge \mu(E) \epsilon^2$ but this contradicts the fact that $\int g_n^2 \to 0$. I was trying to leave this as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

By Tonelli theorem, $\sum\limits_n\int g_n^2\,\mathrm d\mu=\int h\,\mathrm d\mu$ where $h=\sum\limits_ng_n^2$. Assume that the series (of numbers) on the LHS converges. Then $h$ is integrable. Every integrable function is finite almost everywhere hence $h$ is finite almost everywhere. Finally, at each point $x$ such that $h(x)$ is finite, one can be sure that $g_n(x)\to0$ when $n\to\infty$ since the general term of every (numerical) converging series converges to $0$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you also make any comment to my attempt?I am very new in measure theory

Comment: The main problem, which makes that your approach is doomed from the start, is that the cases $\lim g_n(x)=0$ and $\lim g_n(x)\ne0$ are not the only possible cases, since it may well happen that $(g_n(x))$ does not converge when $n\to\infty$.